# Ubuntu 14.04 claiming its HWE is EOL?

Tags: 14.04, updates, update-manager

I was working on my computer running 14.04, and it just gave me this popup:

[image]

Output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

What the heck?

I thought 14.04 was supported for 5 years. What is going on?!

Comment: Did you read the wiki in the link? It clearly explains what is happening.

Comment: @edwinksl - Yes. It says 14.04.5 is supported until 2019.

Comment: Read the first FAQ.

Comment: @edwinksl - But I'm not running 14.04.2. I'm running 14.04.5

Comment: 14.04.2 is provided as an example and the same principle applies to 14.04.5. There is a difference between Ubuntu 14.04 going EOL and the HWE stack going EOL.

Comment: @edwinksl - But if I'm on 14.04.5, shouldn't `apt-get` have installed the latest HWE stack?

Comment: It depends on how you got to/installed 14.04.5. Evidently your kernel isn't as up-to-date as you thought.

Comment: @edwinksl - So what should I do?

Comment: @AndroidDev Maybe upgrade? (but please don't blame me if things go wrong :))